# Using Powershell and HTMLBody.Replace how do I replace values inside an existing table?

Tags: powershell, outlook, powershell-5.1

I have an existing email template file for Outlook with To, CC, Subject and Body prefilled.

I can replace the values I need on the subject just fine, however, when it comes to the HTMLBody part, it only replaces values outside the table; I've tested this by putting all 15 placeholders outside the table.

In Powershell, I defined an array with the items that will be replaced and another that reads the values from a JSON file, then I loop through both in order to replace the values on the HTMLBody.

This is the code in question:

```
$emailToreplaceValues=@(
  "[DailyReportDate]",
  "[DailyReportSuccess]",
  "[DailyReportFailure]",
  "[DailyReportFailureRate]"
)

$newValues=@(
    $valuesJSON.DailyReport.Date,
    $valuesJSON.DailyReport.Success,
    $valuesJSON.DailyReport.Failure,
    $dailyReportFailureRate
  )

$reportEmail = $outlookObj.CreateItemFromTemplate("$emailTemplate")
  $reportEmail.Subject = $reportEmail.Subject.Replace("[date]", $date)

  for($i=0;$i -le $newValues.Count;$i++) {
    $reportEmail.HTMLBody = $reportEmail.HTMLBody.Replace($emailToreplaceValues[$i], $newValues[$i])
  }
```

There's more values but for the sake of brevity, I only included a few of the values, from my understanding, the issue is that some of those values are inside a HTML table cell but I don't know if I can access the table or cells directly.

Comment: You probably are aware but throwing it out there anyways.  .Replace() method is case-sensitive so be sure that the case of the values you are looking for (e.g., [DailyReportDate] ) match exactly how they are in the template

Comment: @Daniel I didn't know but I make a habit of ensuring that.
And like I said in the question, if I put the same value outside the table, they do get replaced.

Comment: I cannot see any reason why this code does not work then.  As a shot in the dark, is the table actually in the template/email, or maybe instead it is embedded/linked from some other location or possibly even an image/screenshot of a table?  If you open the template are you able to make changes to values in the table?

Comment: The table is in the email, not embedded.

Comment: I can try to redo the template since the report is updated manually and sent every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of future reference, the only way I was able to fix this, was by grabbing the html code off the email that I based my email template off.

I organized it so that any tags I want replaced are in their own line without anything else other than the spaces for indentation, then defined it as a variable that goes through the replace cycle and gets assigned to the `MailItem.HTMLBody` property after the replace cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not use `MailItem.HTMLBody` property as variable - it is expensive to set and read, and it might not be the same HTML you set as Outlook performs some massaging and validation. Introduce an explicit variable, set it to the value of `HTMLBody`, do all your string replacements in a loop using that variable, then set the `MailItem.HTMLBody` property once.

You can also try to output the value of that variable to make sure the old values to be replaced are really there and are not broken by HTML formatting or encoding.

Comment: It's definitely the same HTML since I'm reading it from the template file.
If I send it to a variable will I be able to do all the replaces in the same way?

Comment: I think you missed my point - if you set the`HTMLBody` property, and then read it back, it is not guaranteed it will be same as the original HTML.

Comment: Yes, you can do replacements with a variable, only it will be faster - setting a simple variable is faster then setting a property that Outlook will parse and validate, and (potentially) extract it from some other property (e.g., `PR_RTF_COMPRESSED`) when reading it back

Comment: Ah, I see, I'll send the HTMLBody to a variable, do the Replace() on that variable and then set the HTMLBody to that variable.

Comment: For reference, I was following this article on how to do this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/outlook-email-automation-with-powershell/